# Github gist highlight code

Tags: github, gist

I am trying to highlight a few lines of code on gist, but it is not working.

I am trying to follow the example mentioned in this [link](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/07/25/sharing-line-highlights-in-github-files)

https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/36be275685d0d09e3a0140e2a4d929e6/#L10
https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/36be275685d0d09e3a0140e2a4d929e6/#L28-L33

Both the above links are not highlighting the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nearly :-)

Here are the fixed links, highlighting should be working:

https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/36be275685d0d09e3a0140e2a4d929e6#file-soapcreateenvelopefromtemplate-java-L10

https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/36be275685d0d09e3a0140e2a4d929e6/#file-soapcreateenvelopefromtemplate-java-L28-L32

In the future you can click the line number in the sidebar for a single line.

For multiple click the start point, then `shift + click` the last line for the area highlight.

Comment: can you highlight more than one region?

Comment: @ychaouche I tried selecting multiple regions but it only lets you select 1 line or 1 region, hopefully GitHub adds multi line / region selection functionality in the future